# Newly married last name change for wife?

Tags: schengen, weddings

I hold valid Indian passport. I got married recently. We are applying for schengen residence permit / visa.

How important is last name change for my wife in the context of applying for visa? Can she keep her fathers last name as in passport?

What is the difference between last name and spouse name for a lady after marriage?

We have just applied for marriage certificate.

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have valid marriage certificate, the name can be different for you and the spouse. They have a right to have their own name as they would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

This heavily depends on if her name is officially changed or not. While I am not aware of the customs in India, in many countries both parties keep their original names officially, while they use their married name. In others, the name does get changed.

Bottom line is: You will want to use her official name on the visa application, as it appears on the passport she will be using.

Regarding the fields: her mother's name is just that, her mother's name. It can be the same as her last name. Spouse's name should be your name.